# Boot to suspend?

Tags: boot, suspend, nvidia-optimus

I am having a weird issue here that I am not quite sure how to fix!

After thinking for almost an entire day that I have one of those infamous boot to black screen issues that I wasn’t able to fix,  I "fixed" the issue by forcing my laptop into sleep by closing the lid, waiting until the hardware went to sleep, and opening it again to find my login screen sitting there just like expect it to. I can also login and keep working normally from that point onward. So I am basically booting the OS in sleep mode from what I can figure.

This came about because I left the laptop in sleep mode without a power cable over night by accident. My laptop uses, in theory, the nvidia optimus thingy which I believe a lot of users report issues with not working correctly resulting in huge power consumption. This has apparently caused my system to forcefully shut down while in sleep mode.

*How can I reset everything so I boot normally again?*

Comment: Go to *Software & Updates* -> *Additional drivers*, install the suggestion after xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (probably nvidia-331 or something like that) for your graphics card, then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify which exact NVidia hardware you have I can only give a vague answer:

Some "nvidia optimus thingies" take a long time to initialise.  The only recourse is to wait until it boots completely!